# Rails Optimize query and loop through large entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, loops, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a method that outputs the following hash format for charting.

```
# Monthly (Jan - Dec)
{
  "john": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
  "mike": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
  "rick": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
}
# the indices represents the month
# e.g [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
# Index
# 0 = Jan
# 1 = Feb
# 2 = Mar
...
```

---

The following method loops through all the store invoices within given year with specific sales rep name and generate above outcome

```
def chart_data
  hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }

  (1..12).each do |month|
    date_range = "1/#{month}/#{date.year}".to_date.all_month
    all_reps.each do |name|
      hash[name] << store.bw_invoices.where(sales_rep_name: name, 
      purchase_date: date_range).sum(:subtotal).to_f
    end
  end
  return hash
end
```

---

When I run run this method it takes over 4~5 sec to execute. I really need to optimize this query. I came up with two solutions that I think it would help but I would love to get some of your expertise.

1. move it to background job
2. perform a SQL query to optimize(I need help with this if this is optimal)

Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Can you also add some example data? `Reps.all.first(10)` Also, where is `date.year` coming from?

Comment: How are the models connected to each other? What how are `all_reps`, `store`, `bw_invoices` defined or coming from?

Comment: @spickermann store has_many invoices, all_reps are column inside invoices. I just pluck and uniq to fetch all the reps. I hope this helps

Comment: @Vlad thanks for your answer, date.year could just be Date.today.year. If I have more reps than 10 what would happen? because I need to loop through all of them

Comment: Are you using postgresql?

Comment: @Adamantish Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've found a problem that is very hard to solve efficiently without letting the database do the hard work.

Assuming your dataset is potentially too large to load a whole year raw into ruby objects, this approach using just 1 postgreSQL query would be probably the best kind of idea:

### More SQL approach

```
def chart_data
  result = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }

  total_lines = store.bw_invoices.select("sales_rep_name, to_char(purchase_date, 'mm') as month, sum(subtotal) as total")
                                 .where(purchase_date: Date.today.all_year)
                                 .group("sales_rep_name, to_char(purchase_date, 'mm')")                                 

  total_lines.each do |total_line|
    result[total_line.sales_rep_name][total_line.month.to_i - 1] = total_line.total.to_f
  end

  result
end
```

Note that this solution will leave `nil` rather than 0 for months where a rep had no sales. And if their last month with sales was June then there will only be 6 items in the array.

We can avoid this either with more complex SQL left joining from a virtual table or by filling in the array gaps afterwards. However, depending on how you setup your charting this might make no practical difference anyway.

### More ruby approach

```
def chart_data
  result = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }

  (1..12).each do |month|
    date_range = "1/#{month}/#{Date.today.year}".to_date.all_month
    rows = store.bw_invoices.select("sales_rep_name, SUM(subtotal) as total")
                            .where(purchase_date: date_range)
                            .group(:sales_rep_name)

    all_reps.each do |rep_name|
      row = rows.detect { |x| x.sales_rep_name == rep_name }
      result[rep_name] << (row ? row.total : 0).to_f
    end
  end

  result
end
```

This is more similar to your approach but takes the querying outside of the inner loop so we do 12 queries instead of 12 * number of reps. The `detect` used may become a little slow but only if there are thousands of reps. In which case you could sort both `all_reps` and the query output and implement your own kind of [merge join](http://sqlity.net/en/1480/a-join-a-day-the-sort-merge-join/) but at that point you're getting into complexity you might as well let the database handle again.

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback, I didn't get a chance to test the method yet! I am just about to optimize and see if it works ! Thanks again